# How to get values from DataTables row?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, row

I want to get values of a row in DataTables when a click on the button corresponding to this row, but when using this code i get undefined:

The buttons are being added like this:

```
function getdata()
    {
     $pdrs = Pdrs::select('ID_Piece', 'Designation', 'Status');
     $result = DataTables::of($pdrs)
            ...
            ->addColumn('action', function($pdr){
            return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary Ajouter_au_panier" id="'.$pdr->ID_Piece.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Ajouter au panier</a>';})
        ->make(true);   
    return $result ;
    }
```

the trigger is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Ajouter_au_panier', function(){
    var table = $('#pdr_table').DataTable();
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );  
});
```

Comment: What is `this`? We need to see much more of your code in order to help you.

Comment: Does this because adding the buttons manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the trigger in the `<a>` tag inside the cell, you need to reference the parent cell instead of the `<a>`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.Ajouter_au_panier', function(e){
    var table = $('#pdr_table').DataTable();
    console.log( table.row( $(this).closest("td") ).data() );  
});
```

**UPDATE / EDITED:** To get the contents of a specific column, use the `cells()` function with the row and column as params in an object. I.e. for column 2:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Ajouter_au_panier', function(e){
    var table = $('#pdr_table').DataTable();
    var rowId = table.row( $(this).closest("td") ).index();
    console.log( table.cells({ row: rowId, column: 2 }).data()[0] );  
});
```

**UPDATE 2 / EDITED:** If you want to get the contents of the same column where the link was clicked, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Ajouter_au_panier', function(e){
    var table = $('#pdr_table').DataTable();
    var rowId = table.row( $(this).closest("td") ).index();
    var colId = table.column( $(this).closest("td") ).index();
    console.log( table.cells({ row: rowId, column: colId }).data()[0] );  
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this is working, how do i filter this to get only the value of a specific column?

Comment: I get undefined when doing `console.log( table.row( $(this).closest("td") ).data()[2] );`

Comment: Do you have 3 columns and data in the 3rd column? Btw. it's good practice to approve the answer when the **original question** has been answered, not after asking more questions.

Comment: Yes i have that's the result when doing only `data()` `{ID_Piece: "2", Designation: "Ecran", Status: "Indisponible", checkbox: "<input type="checkbox" name="pdr_checkbox[]" class="pdr_checkbox" value="2" />", action: "<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary Ajouter_…yphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Ajouter au panier</a>"}`

Comment: undefined is the result.